# Django; What is preferable way to upload some images?

Tags: python, django

I've been working on Django project. Currently, user can upload only one image but now I want to change it so user can upload some images.

`models.py` is like this.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(...)
```

I am thinking of just adding `photo2` and `photo3` inside Entry model. But I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it. I don't want to delete images that are already uploaded. Anyone who could give me tips? Also, I don't like the file upload form's design and some people use just button-like form. I also want to know how to create button-like form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create new model called 'Photo'.
2. Create [relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/) from 'Entry' to 'Photo'.

If you want to use photos that related with Entry record, you need to use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) function

Also you can find button-like upload form [here.](https://blog.benestudio.co/custom-file-upload-button-with-pure-css-5aacf39aa0a)

Comment: Also please do not remove photo field from 'Entry'. You should define new field to use 'Photo' model relationship.